# Acceptable ground to neutral voltage?

Tags: electrical, grounding

First of all I'm pretty sure I know the theory behind the effect. I know about the inductive and capacitive coupling, about 3-phase balance problems and about ground bounce, so this question isn't about normality of existence of voltage between ground and neutral line.

What I want to know is in general are there established levels at which the voltage is normal, at which I should start investigating the voltage and at which I should kill power and start panicking?

## **!!!PLEASE READ THIS FIRST BEFORE ANSWERING!!!**

Due to recent answers, I added the following section to the question:

First, **I AM AWARE OF OHM'S LAW**! I hoped that it would be obvious from the second sentence of the question, but it isn't.

Second, the type of answer I'm looking for is something like: "The difference in a properly installed should be below XX V because it is written so in regulation YY". Bonus points for information on how number XX has been derived.

Alternatively acceptable answer would be: "There's no limit  in any regulatory documents because of ZZZ." if it's accompanied by a good description of ZZZ.

**I will down-vote answers which basically say: Ohm's law.**

I know that this sounds extremely rude, but unfortunately I don't see any other way to explain exactly what I'm asking. If you don't know the answer, that's fine by me.

Comment: well if it's above what the hot should be carrying you should be panicking

Comment: @ratchet freak  Well I do agree on that. :) It's just that some sources for example say that the voltage should be below 0.5 V (source claimed that exposing cows to Vgn higher than 0.5 V can impact milk production), others say that below 2 V is fine, some say that some computers may work up to 30 V and so on and so on.

Comment: Where are you measuring the voltage?

Comment: @Tester101 At the plug, but I'm looking for general answer.

Comment: It depends on the circuit impedance, if you have a voltage drop of 4V you'll see a 2V voltage differential between neutral and ground.

Comment: "Neutral to ground voltages at branch receptacles are directly proportional to circuit length and circuit current and inversely proportional to conductor size or cross-sectional area. In other words, making the circuit longer or increasing the circuit current will increase the neutral to ground voltage. Increasing the conductor gauge will reduce the neutral to ground voltage that occurs for any given length circuit at any given load." [Source](http://www.bomara.com/powervar/wp-neutral-ground-voltage.htm)

Comment: @Tester101 Yes, I've seen that paper quoted several times, but it doesn't address the main issue.

Comment: Are you talking about neutral to equipment grounding conductor (EGC), or neutral to ground (earth)?

Comment: If you're worried about your cows not giving milk, you'll want to have a look at Article 547 of the National Electrical Code (specifically 547.10). And do some research on "*Equipotential Planes*". In this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAs_FmdxXhQ&list=UU8oJL9T1z3Gqn6drDphZY6g&index=1) Mike Holt talks for an hour and a half about this topic.

Comment: @Tester101 I'm not worried about cows and I don't have any. In that comment, I just mentioned what some articles I've read say about acceptable neutral to ground voltages and some of the problems the articles mention when neutral to ground voltages are higher than values mentioned by the article.

Comment: @Tester101 About the other comment: We have a bit different terminology, but I think that I'm talking about neutral to ground voltage. Here I have a TT grounding system and the  ground conductor I'm talking about is connected to the electrode array berried in the  ground.  I'm not sure how EGC in this kind of set-up would be different from ground.

Comment: Note that this should probably be measured across a suitable load resistor. 120V at 10uA is very different from 120V at 10A, but a simple voltmeter may not distinguish the two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best I could do was to dig up a fine print note (FPN) in the National Electrical Code (NEC). In theory, there is no limit (as stated in other answers). In practice, the limit is when things stop working. In this FPN, the limit is 3-5%. In reality, the limit is around 1-2%.

## NEC 2008

> **210.19 Conductors — Minimum Ampacity and Size.**
> **(A) Branch Circuits Not More Than 600 Volts.**
> **(1) General.**
> ***FPN No. 4:** Conductors for branch circuits as defined in Article 100, sized to prevent a voltage drop exceeding 3 percent at the
> farthest outlet of power, heating, and lighting loads, or combinations
> of such loads, and where the maximum total voltage drop on both
> feeders and branch circuits to the farthest outlet does not exceed 5
> percent, provide reasonable efficiency of operation. See FPN No. 2 of
> 215.2(A)(3) for voltage drop on feeder conductors.*

This *Fine Print Note* (FPN) says that to provide "*reasonable efficiency of operation*", the voltage drop of the branch circuit to the furthest point should not exceed 3%. And that the total voltage drop, including the feeders should not exceed 5%.

`120V * 3% = 3.6V`
`120V * 5% = 6V`

Given this information.  You should start to examine your wiring, if you measure anything near 3V neutral to ground.

<sub>*Note: Fine print notes are informational only and are not enforceable as requirements of the National Electrical Code.*</sub>

Comment: This is much closer to what I'm looking. Thanks!

Comment: Could "reasonable efficiency of operation" simply be referring to power loss in the circuit resistance? As opposed to the tolerance of the load to the voltage between neutral and ground.

Comment: @PhilipNgai The voltage between neutral and ground will be equal to the voltage drop across the wire.

Comment: Since the ground and neutral are tied together at the circuit breaker panel, causing 0 volt ground->neutral there, the metric you want is the 3%. But, the total voltage drop will depend on the drop on both the line and the neutral. So, for the neutral to ground measurement, you'll want half of the 3%. This drop should be much less with 240V loads since there isn't  any current on the neutral line if the load is properly balanced.

Comment: This answer makes even more sense in the context of your other answer, which provides a bit of background on why the difference arises. Maybe they could be combined?

Comment: @Tester101 that wasn't actually what I was asking, but let's drop it.

Answer (score 6):

> **VOLTAGE BETWEEN NEUTRAL AND GROUND**
>
> ***Proper Installation.***
>
> In a proper neutral-to-ground installation, the *voltage between the
>   neutral conductor and any metal part of the electrical system* will be
>   equal to the voltage drop of the neutral conductor in accordance with
>   the following:
>
> 1. At service equipment, the voltage difference between the neutral conductor and the service equipment case will be 0 volts.
> 2. At panelboards, the voltage difference between the neutral conductor and the equipment grounding conductor (panelboard case) will
>      be equal to the voltage drop of the feeder neutral conductor.
> 3. At branch circuits, the voltage difference between the neutral conductor and the equipment ground (ground contacts of the receptacle)
>      will be equal to the voltage drop of the feeder and branch circuit
>      neutral conductors.

[Source](http://www.mikeholt.com/technical.php?id=powerquality/unformatted/NeutralGroundVoltage&type=u&title=Power%20Quality%20Article)

Answer (score 2):

NEC recommends (but does not require) that there is no more than 3% drop on a branch circuit. On a 120V circuit, that would be 3.6V, which would be split across the hot and the neutral, so you wouldn't want to see more than 1.8V on the neutral.

Comment: Please read the question before answering.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on load to load senstivity. It depent on voltage difference between Vnw.r.tg and Vlw.r.tg at any perticular time t. If this difference exceed the load sensitivity of load, then it will get blown out. As it is AC voltage Vnwrtg can be in synch or out of synch therefore can be addition or subtraction at time t and can vary. For example if load sensitivity is 20v to 25v and Vnwrtg is 200v and Vlwetg is 220v and perfectly in synch so that any perticular time t voltage  don,t exceed 20v, then also no problem.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. There's interesting stuff here, but it's hard to understand due to the formatting and unexplained acronyms. If this is important to you, you probably should edit your answer to make it clearer.

Comment: "*Voltage Neutral Wire Referenced to Ground*" and "*Voltage Live Wire Referenced to Ground*", maybe?

Answer (score 0):

As Corporate Trainer for a Large HVAC manufacturer I can say that our equipment cannot reliably prove flame if there is more than a 2.0 volt difference between the neutral and ground

Comment: The question has nothing whatsoever to do with HVAC equipment, at least, according to my reading...

Comment: @FreeMan -- it is a useful datapoint WRT "acceptable" at least

Answer (score -1):

Normally , it is zero.
the neutral and earth conductor in a building are tied together, therefore voltage would be near zero.

Comment: But I'm asking for exact values.